# Magento2: Unable to fetch the surcharge amount added by Fooman_Surcharge extension

Tags: magento2, orders, surcharge

Magento 2.4.6

I am trying to get an orders surcharge amount which was added by the Fooman Surcharge extension.

In Magento 1 it worked with `$order->getFoomanSurchargeAmount();`, in Magento 2 it doesnt work this way.

Any ideas how to get the amount from an order object?

Thanks!

Comment: I;m not familiar with the extension, But I know "Fooman" and I know he does things the right way, so there is a high chance he added an extension attribute for the sircharge. Try it with `$order->getExtensionAttributes()->getFoomanSurchargeAmount()`. If that does not work try logging somewhere `$order->getExtensionAttributes()` and see how it looks like. maybe the attribute name is different

Comment: @Marius please correct the typo: `$order->getExcentionAttributes()` must be `$order-> getExtensionAttributes()` (someone can copy this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surcharges added by our extension are available via extension attributes. As there can be multiple different surcharges there is a top level totals group item. Please see below for an example to get to the surcharges including cases where no surcharges are present:

```
private function processFoomanTotals(\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order)
{
    $extAttr = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
    if (!$extAttr) {
        return;
    }

    $foomanGroup = $extAttr->getFoomanTotalGroup();
    if (empty($foomanGroup)) {
        return;
    }

    $totals = $foomanGroup->getItems();
    if (empty($totals)) {
        return;
    }

    foreach ($totals as $total) {
        /** @var \Fooman\Totals\Api\Data\OrderTotalInterface $total */
        $description = $total->getLabel();
        $baseAmount = $total->getBaseAmount();
        $baseTaxAmount = $total->getBaseTaxAmount();
        $amount = $total->getAmount();
        $taxAmount = $total->getTaxAmount();
        $identifier = $total->getTypeId();
        $qty = 1;
        /** @TODO do something with the total */
    }
}
```

Or as an alternative you could use `Fooman\Totals\Model\OrderTotalManagement::getByCodeAndOrderId($code, $orderId)` where `$code` is `fooman_surcharge`.

Comment: Works like a charm,thanks